# threejs : error when deleting a Geometry or BufferGeometry in combination with a Sprite/Ortho camera

Tags: three.js

I load some objects using the ctm binary loader in Threejs r69. This returns Mesh objects using a BufferGeometry internally.
I need to remove from the scene then delete one of these Meshes, including their material/texture/geometry. According to examples and google, I should use:

```
scene.remove(m_mesh);
m_mesh.geometry.dispose();
m_mesh.geometry = null;
m_mesh.material.dispose();
m_mesh.material = null;
m_mesh = null;
```

This removes the object from the scene, but the screen goes black for a second, and I've got a GL error :

```
Error: WebGL: drawElements: no VBO bound to enabled vertex attrib index 2!
```

Looks like the above sequence (ran in my render() operation, just before drawing the scene) did not clean everything, or at least I still have references to non existing VBOs somewhere.

I've spent quite some time debugging the problem and came to the conclusion that this happens only when using an orthographic camera with a Sprite and a Perspective camera, in 2 differents scenes.

Basically, I draw a flat background using a Sprite and a dedicated scene, then my 3D scene with Meshes. If I delete a mesh from the 3D scene, then the drawing of the flat background fails.
I can't figure out why. Looks like there's a side effect of deleting a Mesh on Sprites, even if attached to different scenes.
If I comment the background drawing, then the deletion of my mesh works perfectly.

I insert below a reproduction of the problem using the standard threejs distribution. Wait about 5 seconds and you should see some GL errors on the jaavscript console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - geometries</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Monospace;
            background-color: #000;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;
        frame_count = 0;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
            camera.position.y = 400;

            // I need a second camera for my 2D sprite (used as a background)
            // must use another texture so that it's not destroyed when removing the first object
            cameraOrtho = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -2,
                window.innerWidth / 2,
                window.innerHeight / 2,
                window.innerHeight / -2,
                1, 10);

            cameraOrtho.position.z = 10;
            cameraOrtho.position.y = 400;
            sceneBackground = new THREE.Scene();

            var map1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/disturb.jpg');
            var material1 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
                map: map1
            });
            var spriteBackground = new THREE.Sprite(material1);
            spriteBackground.scale.set(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 1);

            spriteBackground.position.set(window.innerWidth / 2,
                window.innerHeight / 2);
            sceneBackground.add(spriteBackground);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var light;
            my_object = null;

            scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040));

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
            light.position.set(0, 1, 0);
            scene.add(light);

            var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg');
            map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            map.anisotropy = 16;

            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                map: map,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide
            });

            // one object is enough to demonstrate

            // can't reproduce the problem with a standard SphereGeometry
            // try to convert it to a BufferGeometry
            var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(75, 20, 10);
            var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(sphereGeometry);

            my_object = new THREE.Mesh(bufferGeometry, material);
            my_object.position.set(-400, 0, 200);
            scene.add(my_object);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.autoClear = false;
            renderer.autoClearDepth = false;

            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild(stats.domElement);

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            render();
            stats.update();

        }

        function render() {
            frame_count++;

            var timer = Date.now() * 0.0001;

            camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 800;
            camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 800;

            camera.lookAt(scene.position);


            //after a few frames I want to destroy completely the object
            //means remove from the scene, remove texture, material, geometry
            //note that here it's a Geometry, not a BufferGeometry
            //may be different

            if (frame_count > 60 * 5) {
                if (my_object != null) {

                    console.log("destroy object buffer");
                    scene.remove(my_object);
                    my_object.material.map.dispose();
                    my_object.material.dispose();
                    my_object.geometry.dispose();
                    my_object = null;
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0, l = scene.children.length; i < l; i++) {

                var object = scene.children[i];

                object.rotation.x = timer * 5;
                object.rotation.y = timer * 2.5;

            }

            renderer.render(sceneBackground, cameraOrtho);
            renderer.clearDepth();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any hints on how to fix this issue?

Thank you,

Pascal

Comment: Did you try to set `preserveDrawingBuffer` to `true`? Its a renderer option.

Comment: Hi,That's quite an old thread now, but in case it helps somebody, this appears to be a bug in Threejs, at least until version r71. This happens only for sprites : using for example a textured plane does not trigger the issue.I can't accept my own answer, so if somebody else could accept it for future reference it would be cool.